# Copy arrays from specific indexes

Tags: c#, arrays

How can I copy an array of values to a destination array starting from a specific index without looping?

For example,if I have an array with 2 values, I have to copy those two elements to another array which has a capacity of 5 starting from index 3?

```
 double[] source = new double[] {1, 2};
 double[] destination = new double[5]{0,0,0,0,0};
 //How to perform this copy?
 double[] result = new double[5] {0, 0, 0, 1, 2};
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`Array.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copyto.aspx) or the static method [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft.aspx).

```
source.CopyTo(destination, 3);
```

Comment: Copy of david yaw's... his came first, i have to vote for his.

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III - What has "first" got to do with it? Vote for best answer rather than "first". You do know you can vote for as many answers as you want, right?

Comment: & @Oded, when you first posted, it only had `Use the static method Array.Copy`. Now, it *is* better than @David Yaw's

Comment: @Richard J. Ross III - SO lets you edit answers (and questions) to make them better. Many people post an initial answer then make it better - which is why you should let the dust settle before voting...

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
Array.Copy(source, 0 /*start loc*/, destination, 3 /*start loc*/, 2 /*count*/);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double[] source = new double[] {1, 2};
 double[] destination = new double[5]{0,0,0,0,0};
 //How to perform this copy?
ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
result.AddRange(source);
result.AddRange(destination);
destination = result.ToArray();
```

Comment: I dont think that this is the answer he was looking for, as it doesn't quite only do that from the specified indices